# SSH Setup and Key Generation

Tags: ssh

I am referring to the [following](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm) tutorial and following the below steps:

> #### SSH Setup and Key Generation
>
> SSH setup is required to do different operations on a cluster such as
>   starting, stopping, distributed daemon
>   shell operations. To authenticate different users of Hadoop, it is
>   required to provide public/private key pair for a Hadoop user and
>   share it with different users.
>
> The following commands are used for generating a key value pair using
>   SSH. Copy the public keys form id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys, and
>   provide the owner with read and write permissions to authorized_keys
>   file respectively.
>
> ```
> $ ssh-keygen -t rsa 
> $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
> $ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```

When I run the first step `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa` in my command prompt as shown below:

[image]

1. It's asking me to enter the file for saving. I am new to Linux and wondering which file I would need to enter and in which folder it will get saved?
2. In the second step, do I need to create `authorized_keys` folder somewhere?

   ```
   $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply proper formatting. By the way, questions on Fedora should be asked at [unix.se]. `authorized_keys` is not a folder, but a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As a beginner, just press enter to use the defaults recommended by your OS. It will automatically use the values recommended in the parentheses.
2. No, the system will automatically create the necessary files and folders for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be in root otherwise it will create this file in root. close the terminal and open it again to exit root. then run this command and when it asks for location enter the suggested address usually like this:

```
/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and "*authorized keys*" is a file not a folder.system creates it automatically.

Comment: I already created while I was in root before your answer. Is that gonna create any problem?

Comment: no. based on my experience it doesn't cause any problem.